# No' Overload for method 'Normalize' takes 1 arguments error code: CS1501

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on creating a clone of Billiards in 2D; I'm fairly new to coding in general but I have used the Normalize method a few times and never had this issue. I have removed "using System.Numerics" since it was causing an issue with 'Vector2'.

The variable "shootDistance" is a float with no value assigned.

```
  Vector2 dimxy = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;
    float difference = dimxy.magnitude;

    mousePointB.transform.position = (Vector2)transform.position + ((dimxy / difference) * currDistance * -1);
    mousePointB.transform.position = new UnityEngine.Vector2(mousePointB.transform.position.x, mousePointB.transform.position.y);

    shootDirection = Vector2.Normalize(mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize **takes Vector3 or Vector2 but returns a Vector3**, so you cast to Vector2 the return value, you have to write:  (positionB and positionA are Vector3 or Vector2)

```
shootDirection = (Vector2)Vector3.Normalize(positionB - positionA);
```

convert Vector2 to Vector3 is implicit with z=0

but Vector3 to Vector2 is not implicit so its the reason you have to specify the cast and in this case you loose the z value